# Having firebase and AngularFire2 in the same app

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

I have found myself using firebase as well as AngularFire2 in the same app.

The question I have is do I need to initialize both of them individually?

I am configurin my angularfire instance as follows

```
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
```

and for the firebase one i do the following

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

Will any one do or both need to be initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to configure like this

```
 AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

which will initialize `firebase`.

`Angularfire2` not come with all features of `firebase`, so if you want to use firebase's native methods, just import this your component.ts

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

Comment: but I have to initialize it once. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to do this 'firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)' again if you are following angularfire2 way.